# AGORA :I want to remove localstream when call ends

Tags: agora.io

I want to remove `localstream` when call ends. I am using

```
var localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({audio: true, video: true});
localStream.removeTrack(localStream.getAudioTrack());
```

but giving me error

> localstream.getAudioTrack is not a function

Please help actually I want to remove localstream when call ends
I am writing that code in

```
this.client.on('peer-leave', function (evt)
```

Answer (score 0):

function localStream.getAudioTrack() is not supported in AGORASDK2.4.0.js(version)
if you want to use this function must use the version 2.5 and Greater version.
and then use the functions from Agora Documentation according to the version which you are using.